# Trying to replicate iPhone keyboard button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have an application where I'm trying to implement my own custom keyboard. This custom keyboard will look almost exactly like the default iPhone system keyboard with little twists here and there to match my app (ie color, font, etc.).

My first step is trying to replicate the standard keyboard button. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I tried retrieving the keyboard (via sifting through UIWindows subviews) and was able to accomplish this, however when I looked at the keyboards subviews to try and retrieve the custom button, it appeared the keyboard barely had enough subviews to constitute all the buttons that it contains. On a different question, someone mentioned that the keyboard buttons are not actual views and are drawn on the keyboard view. Given that I have the UIKeyboards view, is there anyway to retrieve the drawing parameters from this to figure out how to draw the buttons like apple does (I'm not too familiar with drawing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LKNumberPad](https://github.com/lakesoft/LKNumberPad) seems to have got it down pat:

[image]

Comment: Cool!  +1, do you know of one for the iPad?

Comment: No, but I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to adjust the rect of each button, seeing as the ipad keys are just more square than the iphone

Comment: Well, they don't have the same animation either, and other visual differences.  Just checking to see if you already knew of something though.  Thanks anyway!